# How to get wireless access point information from MacOS terminal

Tags: networking, osx, wifi

I'm trying to gather information about surrounding access points

but can't find the right tools to do that.

For Linux there are tools like iwconfig and iwlist, but it looks like they are not available for MacOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but with `airport` you can obtain various information from wireless networks/your connection:

e.g.

`sudo airport -s` gives information about all the networks in range (such as RSSI strength).

`sudo airport -I` gives information about your connection, e.g.:

```
     agrCtlRSSI: -66
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -93
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station
     lastTxRate: 351
        maxRate: 1300
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: aa:bb:cc:11:22:33
           SSID: mycoolwifi
            MCS: 2
  guardInterval: 400
            NSS: 3
        channel: 48,80
```

The path to `airport` is:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

Comment: Looks like my Mac OS version does not have airport preinstalled, at least I don't have a airport executable. Running Mac OS X 10.7.4

Comment: my bad: you do have it:
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
see also: http://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/

Answer (score 0):

Under macOS 10.14.6, the SSID of the network you are currently connected to can be gathered with the following command:

```
ioreg -l -n AirPortDriver | grep IO80211SSID | sed 's/^.*= "\(.*\)".*$/\1/; s/ /_/g
```